# Are Ratchet 2 Popovers working?

Tags: ratchet-2

Documentation says

> Popovers are designed to only fire from title bars. Set the value of the title href to the id of a popover, like so:

However I have added to the sample template but does not work for me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ratchet template page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link href="_/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="_/js/ratchet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
      <a href="#myPopover">
        <h1 class="title">Favoritos <span class="icon icon-caret"></span></h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="content-padded">Thanks for downloading Ratchet. This is an example HTML page that's linked up to compiled Ratchet CSS and JS, has the proper meta tags and the HTML structure. Need some more help before you start filling this with your own content? Check out some Ratchet resources:</p>
      <div class="card">
        <ul class="table-view">
          <li class="table-view-cell">
            <a class="push-right" href="http://goratchet.com">
              <strong>Ratchet documentation</strong>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="table-view-cell">
            <a class="push-right" href="https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/">
              <strong>Ratchet on Github</strong>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="table-view-cell">
            <a class="push-right" href="https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/goratchet">
              <strong>Ratchet Google group</strong>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="table-view-cell">
            <a class="push-right" href="https://twitter.com/goratchet">
              <strong>Ratchet on Twitter</strong>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- POPOVER - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <div id="myPopover" class="popover">
      <header class="bar bar-nav">
        <h1 class="title">Popover title</h1>
      </header>
      <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item1</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item2</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item3</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item4</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item5</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item6</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item7</li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">Item8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </body>
</html>
```

What could I be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine... You have to test your code on a mobile device, or emulate a mobile device, because ratchet only responds to "Touch" events and not "Click" events.